# Python Docstrings in Subclasses

Tags: python, class, nested, docstring

I'm creating a class in Python, which then has some nested classes added using setattr().

```
class T( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        cDict = {}
        cDict['__doc__'] = 'Inner class doc string'
        setattr( self, 'C', type('C', (), cDict ) )
```

However, calling help( T ) does not then include and information about C. Constructing a T, and then a C within it, works fine.

Doing this the traditional way works fine:

```
class T2( object ): 
    class C2( object ):
        __doc__ = 'Inner class doc string'
```

Calling help( T2 ) displays information about C2.

Can somebody shed some light on what's happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two snippets you showed are not equivalent.

This:

```
class T( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        cDict = {}
        cDict['__doc__'] = 'Inner class doc string'
        setattr( self, 'C', type('C', (), cDict ) )
```

will set a `C` attribute on each `T` instance:

```
>>> T.C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'T' has no attribute 'C'
>>> t = T()
>>> t.C
<class '__main__.C'>
```

This is because you placed the setattr inside `__init__`.

While this:

```
class T2( object ): 
    class C2( object ):
        __doc__ = 'Inner class doc string'
```

will add an attribute on `T2` itself:

```
>>> T2.C2
<class '__main__.C2'>
```

Answer (score 2):

`help` operates on classes and types, rather than objects. However, your `T` only has the member `C` in objects (when `__init__` has been run). So `help` can't detect it.

Your `T2` also contains `C2` in the class itself, so `help` detects it and displays the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

The first way causes `C` to be an instance attribute of each `T` object.

The second way causes `C` to be a class attribute of the `T` class.

`help(T)` provides help on the `T` class (well, the object that the name `T` refers to, which in this case is a class). It can't know anything about any given instance of `T`, even if it's true for every instance (and it might not be, anyway; later code could do `my_T = T(); del my_T.C`).